# The datetime format changes during automation. Why?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using selenium to test an application. I've used execute_script function gets the date and time. It works perfectly but the problem is the date and month gets swapped while automating. Here is my code snippet.

```
start_time = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="start-time"]')
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "2024-02-20 16:00"', start_time)
```

The `execute_script` takes the correct values of dd/mm/yyyy. The original format dd/mm/yyyy changes to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - where is the date format getting swapped? Also, your sample uses `yyyy-mm-dd`, which isn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: The format in the sample is yyyy-mm-dd since execute_script just sets the value. Here is the sample image.
https://github.com/Keerthana-17/Automation/assets/70113034/b495493d-14d3-4493-8753-ce3d1b73664f

Comment: Is it just that your website renders the date in a local date format? That's how `<input type="date">` fields work... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Yes! Here the field used is `<input type='datetime-local'`

Comment: It sound like there's no issue then - the onscreen date is just the local representation of the value. The underlying value in the field will still be what you set it to.

Comment: The problem is not actually with setting the values. The original format before executing is 'dd/mm/yyyy' and when it is automated it changes to 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the date format expected by the input field in your web application. The execute_script function is simply setting the value of the input field to the string you've provided, and it doesn't perform any date format conversion.

If the input field expects the date in the mm/dd/yyyy format, then providing a date in the yyyy-mm-dd format could lead to the day and month being swapped if both are valid month numbers (i.e., less than or equal to 12).

To fix this, you should provide the date in the format expected by the input field. If it expects mm/dd/yyyy, then you should provide the date in that format:

```
start_time = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="start-time"]')
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "02/20/2024 16:00"', start_time)
```

Comment: This doesn't set a single value and thanks for responding.